# Json Deserialize by Jil throw Exception

Tags: json, jil

i have this piece of code:

```
//JSON is in Jil library
var a = JSON.Deserialize(@"{""PhoneNumber"": ""09214523155"",""Password"": ""1928160"",""Token"": ""string"",""SubSystem"": ""string"",""Version"": 0,""DeviceType"": 0} ", typeof(LoginContactInput), Options.ISO8601);
```

and it is my `LoginContactInput` class and `DeviceType` enum:

```
public class LoginContactInput 
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string SubSystem { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; } //DeviceType is an Enum
}
 public enum DeviceType
{
    Mobile,
    Server
}
```

but this throw an exception that says : `Expected character: '"'`

i think my json is correct

what is wrong?

Comment: Can you add the definition for `LoginContactInput` (and any other types it uses)?  It's probably a mismatch between that and the JSON string.

Comment: @KevinMontrose if i remove "DeviceType" from string it works,why?